# Setting event listener of a class property

Tags: javascript, oop, leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I'm using Leaflet and Leaflet-geoman in conjunction with wfs-t to create an editable map object.  I have a class EditMap that has a leaflet map as a property.  I'm trying to listen for the 'pm:create' event on this map for every class.  Here is my code:

```
class EditMap {
    constructor(map){
        this.map = map;//Leaflet map
    }
    this.map.on('pm:create', e => {
        console.log('Feature created');
    });
}
```

I get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' on this line:

```
this.map.on('pm:create', e => {
```

I expect I'm missing something simple.  My basic questions boils down to: How do you listen for an event on an object property?

Comment: That line is outside your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wrong place

You're using a class so you could do:

```
class EditMap {
  constructor(map) {
    this.map = map;

    this.map.on('pm:create', this.pmCreate)
  }

  pmCreate(e) {
    console.log('Feature created');
  }
}
```

or simply this; but will fill out quickly as you add other listerners:

```
class EditMap {
  constructor(map) {
    this.map = map; //Leaflet map

    this.map.on('pm:create', e => {
      console.log('Feature created');
    });
  }
}
```